# Wordpress 5.9 and wp_lazy_loading_enabled filter issue on images

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

since WP 5.5, I had to add this function to my theme to prevent rendering issues in an image slider due to automatic lazy loading in WP:

```php
    add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

This was working quite well since it was removing the automatic parameter "loading=lazy" on images elements.

Yesterday, after upgrading to WP 5.9, I'm facing the same issue again with my slider and I see that the "loading=lazy" parameter is back on all images!

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Please see the change log for this function to see if there's any changes needed in the hook: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.9/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1731-L1748

Comment: Are you using a plugin for your slider? I haven't seen an issue with this filter (using it for the same reason you are) after upgrading to 5.9.

Comment: No, no plugin here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these two solutions:

```
$attr['loading'] = false;
return wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

Or:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    if ( $attachment->post_mime_type === 'image/svg+xml' ) {
        unset( $attr['loading'] );
    }
    return $attr;
} );
```

Answer is from here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_lazy_loading_enabled/#comment-4226

Comment: All filters solutions didn't worked but forcing 'loading' attribute while printing the image solved my problem! Thanks Cray